# Mobile first when using match media?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page that uses multiple form elements. Far too many for a smartphone without scrolling, which I don't want. To solve this problem, I put the form elements in a carousel.

When I don't need the carousel (larger displays) I need to eliminate it. The only way I know of to do this is to reassign the parent properties of the carousel items and then remove the carousel.

This approach works fine using java-script. However, to pull this off I would need to use match media to call the java-script functions. Since most legacy browsers (which don't support match media) are used by desktops wouldn't this go against mobile first development?

Would it be wiser to design for legacy browsers and then upgrade the page for newer, more robust devices that can understand more updated languages or am I approaching this problem entirely wrong? I would rather not add a polyfill to fix this problem if I don't have to. Forgive my ignorance if I'm not seeing the simple solution here.

Here is a snippet that changes the parent div for large displays at codepen.

```
// Transfer elements from carousel to a larger div display
function SetParentDiv() {
  var newParent = document.getElementById('LargeDisplayPage');
  var oldParent = document.getElementById('1');

// Carousel items are 3 divs with numbered id's
  for (var x=1; x < 4; x++) {
    oldParent = document.getElementById(x);
    while (oldParent.childNodes.length > 0) {
      newParent.appendChild(oldParent.childNodes[0]);
    }; ///endwhile
  }; // endfor

document.getElementById('SmallDevicePage').style.display = 'none';

...
```

**[Here is the full Code Pen](http://codepen.io/zorfox/pen/XdRQXY)**

Comment: Yeah, I'd say you're pretty seriously overcomplicating this. You could pretty much hack what you want without any JavaScript at all, simply adding something like this into your 519px media query:
`
  .carousel-indicators {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .carousel-inner > .item {
    display: block;
  }
`

Comment: I never thought of that. I'm an old school Windows developer. Typically, when you hide a "panel" all children are hidden as well. I did NOT know this was an option. SWEET!. Thank you sir!

Comment: @thewatcheruatu , If you'll post your comment as an answer I will mark as accepted. I'm new here and see no way to close this as answered since it was a comment. Thanks again.